# gradle-wrapper.properties file from url?

Tags: url, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I want to able fetch `gradle-wrapper.properties` from another url,
or any setting from other url.

for example, in gradle itself i can fetch setting from another url by simply

`apply from: "https://my.url.com"`

can i do the same for `gradle-wrapper.properties` file?

look this [issue](http://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/issues/47)

===================================================================

there a two option to update gradle version:

[nightly](https://gradle.org/nightly)

[Wrapper](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html)

[gradle_wrapper](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

it say update wrapper properties file OR configure the Wrapper task? why there two option to update gradle version. i didn't succeed update gradle version with gradle Wrapper task. it always listen to properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not a way to do that short of creating your own version of the wrapper.

Why do you want to do that?  It largely defeats the purpose of the wrapper (scripts+wrapper jar+properties is enough to bootstrap an entire Gradle install).

---

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  The version of Gradle to use with your project is a part of your project's configuration and should be checked in.  I don't believe you're saving yourself any time/trouble by making this a part of some external configuration.

- If there was a way to pull the version of Gradle from another file/URL and your build only works for Gradle 1.0 today, that file would say use Gradle 1.0.  Let's say you update your build to use Gradle 2.0 (and update the external file).  If you then need to rebuild your project when it only worked with Gradle 1.0, you can't now without manually tweaking the gradle-wrapper.properties.
- Similarly, if you have a couple of projects that all use the same external file mechanism, when you update one to work with Gradle 2.0, you must update the other one at the same time.
- You could upload your own gradle.zip, but I believe if you overwrite that gradle.zip, the wrapper won't try to redownload it for awhile (if ever).  So while everyone would be using the same URL to download Gradle, some would have an "old" gradle.zip and some would have a "new" gradle.zip.  There wouldn't be a way to distinguish them, so you'd have to tell everyone to nuke their ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists any time you changed gradle.zip.

[We have a new PR to make updating the wrapper easier (should be in 2.4).](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/400)

Gradle releases are fairly predictable, so unless you have 100's of projects, it seems like the problems with trying to get an external gradle-wrapper.properties working outweigh any benefit.

Comment: Thanks, I fear my idea was not work because the reason you mention. 

and maybe need to look more further.
But We need the solution some how.
Where i can post at gredle to ask that feature?
Are you gradle developer?

Comment: why on this [link](https://gradle.org/nightly), it say update wrapper properties file OR configure the Wrapper task? why there two option to update gradle version. i didn't succeed update gradle version with gradle Wrapper task. it always listen to properties file.

Comment: The wrapper task is used to generate the properties file.  So you'd update the wrapper task and then re-run 'gradle wrapper'